# How can HTML <small> tag affect the CSS line-height property?

Tags: html, css, font-size

First `li`'s height is `45px`. Second `li`'s one is `46px`. Why?

```css
div {
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  background-color: #b6ff00;
}
li {
  line-height: 45px;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
li > a {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: inherit;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ff6a00;
}
li:first-child > a {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">dfdd</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><small>sdaf</small>abc</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Because the half-leading of the `<small>` text is 1px larger that the half-leading of the strut that it shares the line with, so the distance from the top of the strut to the bottom to the inline box of the text is 1px greater than their individual line heights.

Comment: I [don't see this being the case](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VbNc4.png) in my browser. Both LI elements have a height of 45 px.  Could you please include the browser information and possibly a screen shot of it showing 46 px height in the question?

Comment: You can fix it with `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align: bottom`.

Comment: @MichaelT The second one is 1px taller than the first one (at least on Firefox). But devtools say both have a computed `line-height` of `45px`.

Comment: @Alohci How fix this problem? i add vertical-align ,but invalid

Comment: The second one is probably also 45px but you could be seeing the 1px margin border or padding from the previous element.  Try 3 list items to see if it looks like it is 45 + 1 between each line.   Another way to say this is that the first item does not have a previous li to have a bottom margin or border or padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is changing `display:block;` to `display:flex;` for `<a>` tag.

```css
div {
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  background-color: #b6ff00;
}
li {
  line-height: 45px;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
li > a {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: inherit;
  /* REMOVED */
  /*display: block;*/
  display: flex; /* added*/
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ff6a00;

}
li:first-child > a {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">dfdd</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><small>sdaf</small>abc</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Alochi. Half-leading is the culprit. [Read this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/inline-format.html) to know more about Half-leading and how it is calculated.

And work around to this problem is adding a `height:45px;` to your `<a>` tag.

```css
div {
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  background-color: #b6ff00;
}
li {
  line-height: 45px;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
li > a {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: inherit;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ff6a00;
  height:45px; /* ADDED*/
  
}
li:first-child > a {
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">AAAA</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><small>AAAA</small>AAA</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```